# Tomact7 chef cookbook ssl problems

Tags: tomcat7, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to set up a chef recipe for automatic deployment of my app over ssl with tomcat chef cookbook.
It works fine without ssl, but when I try to set the attributes for ssl support I'm getting error:

```
undefined method `truststore_password' for Custom resource tomcat_instance from cookbook tomcat.
```

My role:

```
name "myapp"
override_attributes ({
    "java" => { 
        "jdk_version"=> "6"
    },
    "oracle" => {
        "accept_oracle_download_terms" => true
    },
    "tomcat" => {
        "base_version" => 7,
        "java_options" => "${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx128M -Djava.awt.headless=true",
        "secure" => true,
        "client_auth" => true,
        "scheme" => "https",
        "ssl_enabled_protocols" => "TLSv1",
        "keystore_password" => "mypass",
        "truststore_password" => "mypass",
        "ciphers" => "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "keystore_file" => "/etc/tomcat7/client.jks",
        "truststore_file" => "/etc/tomcat7/cert.jks"
    }
})
run_list "recipe[java]", "recipe[tomcat]"
```

Maybe I'm missing something, because I can't find any good tutorials on how to do this I'm also using chef-solo with vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Tomcat cookbook documentation, you will see the following regarding the truststore_password attribute:

```
node['tomcat']['truststore_password'] - Generated by the secure_password method from the 
                                        openssl cookbook; if you are using Chef Solo, 
                                        set this attribute on the node
```

Perhaps this means that you can not set the attribute in your role definition whilst using Chef Solo, and you have to manually add it to the node attributes JSON file.